# How to use the cl command?

Tags: python, c, compiler-construction

All, I found a piece of information on how to call c files in python, in these examples: there is a c file, which includes many other header files, the very beginning of this c files is `#include Python.h`, then I found that  `#include Python.h` actually involves many many other header files, such as  `pystate.h`,  `object.h`, etc, so I include all the required header files. In an cpp IDE environment, it did not show errors. **What I am trying to do is call this c code in python**, so  `from ctypes import *`, then it seems that a `dll` should be generated by code such as: `cl -LD test.c -test.dll`, but how to use the `cl` in this case? I used the cygwin: `gcc`, it worked fine. Could anyone help me with this **i.e.: Call the C in python**? Do I make myself clear? Thank you in advance!!

Well, Now I feel it important to tell me what I did:
The ultimate goal I wanna achieve is:
I am lazy, I do not want to re-write those c codes in python, (which is very complicated for me in some cases), so I just want to generate `dll`
files that python could call. I followed an example given by googleing "python call c", there are two versions in this examples: linux and windows:
The example `test.c`:

```
#include <windows.h>
BOOL APIENTRY  
DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)  {  
    return TRUE;  
}  
__declspec(dllexport) int 
multiply(int num1, int num2)  {  
    return num1 * num2;  
}
```

Two versions:
1, Complie under linux

```
gcc -c -fPIC test.c  
gcc -shared test.o -o test.so
```

I did this in cygwin on my vista system, it works fine; :)

2, Compile under windows:

```
cl -LD test.c -test.dll
```

I used the cl in windows command line prompt, it won't work!

These are the python codes:

```
from ctypes import *   
import os  
libtest = cdll.LoadLibrary(os.getcwd() + '/test.so')  
print test.multiply(2, 2)
```

Could anyone try this and tell me what you get? thank you!

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Python, you are just asking how to run the Microsoft toolchain's compiler on the command line. Please consider tagging your question accordingly.

Comment: @Jim: maybe I should add: how to generate a dll file from c so that python could call it, as in windows, the IDE gives annoying noises which has nothing to do the code itself

Comment: See, maybe your real problem then is related to that "noise" you experience, but instead you already proposed a solution yourself, namely compiling from the command line. You could've instead asked about how to configure your IDE to get rid of that noise, or, if the noise is meaningful in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the command line options of Microsoft's C++ compiler [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610ecb4h(VS.80).aspx).

Consider the following switches for cl:

```
/nologo /GS /fp:precise /Zc:forScope /Gd
```

...and link your file using

```
/NOLOGO /OUT:"your.dll" /DLL <your lib files> /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MACHINE:X86 /DYNAMICBASE
```

Please have a look at what those options mean in detail, I just listed common ones. You should be aware of their effect nonetheless, so try to avoid copy&paste and make sure it's really what you need - the documentation linked above will help you. This is just a setup I use more or less often.

Be advised that you can always open Visual Studio, configure build options, and copy the command line invokations from the project configuration dialog.

**Edit:**
Ok, here is some more advice, given the new information you've edited into your original question. I took the example code of your simple DLL and pasted it into a source file, and made two changes:

```
#include <windows.h>
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return TRUE;  
} 

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall multiply(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1 * num2;  
}
```

First of all, I usually expect functions exported from a DLL to use stdcall calling convention, just because it's a common thing in Windows and there are languages who inherently cannot cope with cdecl, seeing as they only know stdcall. So that's one change I made.

Second, to make exports more friendly, I specified extern "C" to get rid of [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). I then proceeded to compile the code from the command line like this:

```
cl /nologo /GS /Zc:forScope /Gd c.cpp /link /OUT:"foobar.dll" /DL kernel32.lib /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MACHINE:X86
```

If you use the DUMPBIN tool from the Visual Studio toolset, you can check your DLL for exports:

```
dumpbin /EXPORTS foobar.dll
```

Seeing something like this...

```
ordinal hint RVA      name
    1    0 00001010 ?multiply@@YGHHH@Z
```

...you can notice the exported name got mangled. You'll usually want clear names for exports, so either use a DEF file to specify exports in more details, or the shortcut from above.

Afterwards, I end up with a DLL that I can load into Python like this:

```
In [1]: import ctypes

In [2]: dll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("foobar.dll")

In [3]: dll.multiply
Out[3]: <_FuncPtr object at 0x0928BEF3>

In [4]: dll.multiply(5, 5)
Out[4]: 25
```

Note that I'm using ctypes.windll here, which implies stdcall.

Comment: Can you edit your question to hint at the current state or your problem, i.e. including what you have tried so far, what error messages you get, and what/why you think it is not working.

Comment: Sure, sorry, I went out for something, so I didn't not see your post, I will post them now, many thanks to you